# Flutter: Detecting changes in the API

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have a simple API but my flutter widgets could not detect the changes happening in the API without restarting the whole application.

The API was made as a test API on https://www.mockable.io/. I managed to read from this API using a [StreamBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). And still it does not change the values in the widget whenever i update their value in the API.

**Default JSON**

```
{
 "id": "123",
 "token": "1token",
 "status": "Valid"
}
```

**After Value Change**

```
{
 "id": "123",
 "token": "1token",
 "status": "Not Valid"
}
```

**My StreamBuilder Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final String url = "http://demo2722084.mockable.io/user";

class StreamPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  StreamPageState createState() {
    return new StreamPageState();
  }
}

class StreamPageState extends State<StreamPage> {

  StreamController _userController;

  Future fetchUser() async{
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return json.decode(response.body);
    }else{
      print("Exception caught: Failed to get data");
    }
  }

  loadUser() async{
    fetchUser().then((res) async{
      _userController.add(res);
      return res;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _userController = new StreamController();
    loadUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Stream"),
      ),
      body: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: _userController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot){

          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print("Exception: ${snapshot.error}");
          }

          if(snapshot.hasData){

            var user = snapshot.data;

            var id = user["id"] ?? "";
            var token = user["token"] ?? "";
            var status = user["status"] ?? "";

            return new Center(
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text("Token: $token"),
                subtitle: new Text("Status: $status"),
                leading: new Text(id),
              ),
            );
          }

          if(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting){
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          if(!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expected the StreamBuilder to pick up the changed **status** value but the app has to be restarted for the new value to be reflected in the app.

Is there an example of how I can achieve this properly since this is quite frankly my first time trying out a StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your HTTP request results in just one data point, so for that you could use a `FutureBuilder`. But you want to know when something changes at the server. Your HTTP connection has finished when the change is made and so has no idea that it has happened.

There are several ways to detect changes at the server, for example, polling, user-initiated refresh, websockets, etc. For demonstration purposes, instead of calling `loadUser` in `initState` you could start a 1 second periodic timer to do that, which would update the stream every second and you should see the change. (Don't forget to cancel the timer in `dispose`.)

That's unlikely to be viable in production, so explore websockets, etc for pushed notifications from the web server. Also explore whether Firebase Cloud Messaging is a better way to send notification of changes to your application.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _userController = StreamController();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => loadUser());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, Richard. I'll try checking out websockets.

Answer (score 0):

you probably also need to do this only while the app is in foreground. You can use my LifecycleAwareStreamBuilder, there is an example on how to use it [here](https://medium.com/@josuejulcarima/lifecycle-aware-streambuilder-in-flutter-a2ae7244af32)